# Measure-preserving map between a function and its symmetric rearrangement

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, decreasing-rearrangements

Let $f \, \colon \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ be a function such that the sets $ \{ y \: \colon f(y) > \lambda \}$ are of finite Lebesgue-measure, for every $\lambda \geq 0$. Then, we can define the spherically symmetric and decreasing rearrangement $f^* \, \colon \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of $f$ by 
\begin{equation*}
f^* (x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \chi_{ \{f > t \}^*} (x) \,  \textrm{d}t.
\end{equation*} 
Due to a theorem of John V. [Ryff](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X70900387), in the $1$-dimensional case, there is a measure-preserving map $\sigma$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
f=  f^* \circ \sigma  \quad \textrm{ a.e.}
\end{equation*}
(In fact, this is a corollary of the cited theorem and can be found in [1, Corollary 7.6 in chapter 2].) My question is now:

> Is there a similar statement when $d \geq 2$?

I expect that the answer is yes, but, unfortunately, I haven't found a reference. I would be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

[1] Bennett, C., Sharpley, R. *Interpolation of operators*